# Summing Values from Different Sheets for the Same Cell Address

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to sum values from the first sheet to the actual sheet.

Here is what I did:

- The Sum : `=SUM('Sheet1:Here I have to put the actual sheet'!O1187)`
- Find the actual sheet: `=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,256)`

How can I combine both in order to get my values ?

Comment: So on *Sheet8* the formula should behave like:  **=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet8!O1187)** but where the *Sheet8* part comes from the *MID()* formula ??

Comment: yes that's right

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with a little table of values from each sheet.  This will work if your sheets are named *Sheet1*, *Sheet2*, ...........

In **K1** enter:

```
="Sheet" & ROWS($1:1)
```

and in **L1** enter:

```
=INDIRECT(K1 & "!O1187")
```

Copy these downward:

[image]

Now we have all the **O1187** cell values from all sheets.  We put your *MID()* formula in **C1** *(to get the name of the sheet we are on)* and in **D1** enter:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("L1:L"&MATCH(C1,K:K,0)))
```

which sums up the proper section of the table:

[image]

This is the same as `=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet5!O1187)`

Comment: At each sheet I need to get the sum if you see what I mean ?  So if I am at the Sheet 3 I need to see the sum of Sheet 1 to Sheet 3 and so on...

Comment: I find out something  but I get the result as #REF!  here is the formula =SUM(indirect("'Sheet1:"&MID(CELL("filename",A3),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A3))+1,256)&"'!O1187"))